# Node.js login/register Redis problems

Tags: node.js, redis

```
};
var login = function(name, socket, passcode, callback) { 
    db.get(name + ':name', function(res) {
        db.get(name + ':pin', function(pin) {
            if (name === res) {
                if (passcode === pin) {
                    players[sockets.indexOf(socket)] = name;
                }
            }
        });
    });
};
var register = function(name, socket, passcode, callback) {
    if (name === null) {
        callback('Name null!');
        return;
    }
    if (name === '') {
        callback('Name empty!');
        return;
    }
    db.get(name + ':name', function(data) {
        if (data !== null) {
        callback('This name has been taken!');
    }
    else {
        db.set(name + ':name', name, function() {
            db.set(name + ':pin', passcode, function() {
                players[sockets.indexOf(socket)] = name;
                callback('Logged in as: ' + players[sockets.indexOf(socket)]);
            });
        });
    }
});
};
```

Why does the login part let me login with any PIN to any user, and the register part not callback?

They are called via

```
   login(args[1], socket, args[2], function(data) {
        callback(null, data)
    }
```

db is a redis client.

Full code: github.com/creativemud, file server.js

Answer (score 1):

You never execute the callback inside `login`. You need to call `callback` when you're done.

Also, you seem to lack some error handling. Is `db` a redis client? In that case, the first parameter to every callback is an error, which is custom in node.js land. I would do something like:

```
var login = function(name, socket, passcode, callback) { 
    db.get(name + ':name', function(err, res) {
        if(err) return callback(err);

        if(res !== name) return callback(new Error('invalid result'));

        db.get(name + ':pin', function(err, pin) {
            if(err) return callback(err);

            if(pin !== passcode) return callback(new Error('invalid passcode'));

            players[sockets.indexOf(socket)] = name;
            callback(null, name);
        });
    });
};
```

Might not be very clean, but I hope you catch the drift.

**Edit:** You don't show how you call these functions. Socket.io has pretty nice support for authentication, you might want to check it out: [Authorization and handshaking](https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/wiki/Authorizing).